# Xen PVM host showing wrong info about Cpu core and socket

Tags: xen, cpu-usage

I have XEN install on a machine which has 2 sockets of 4 core each. So total 8 core and each core have 2 thread. So the server have 48 logical CPU.

```
[root@xen ~]# xm info
release                : 4.1.12-94.6.4.x86_64
nr_cpus                : 48
nr_nodes               : 2
cores_per_socket       : 12
threads_per_core       : 2
```

I have assigned 8 core on a paravirtualized guest machine. It shows correct info about number of cpu but it shows wrong info about core and sockets. [If it is showing correct info then please explain why]

```
[arif@vm ~]$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    8
Core(s) per socket:    1
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 62
Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.70GHz
Stepping:              4
CPU MHz:               2693.552
BogoMIPS:              5387.22
Hypervisor vendor:     Xen
Virtualization type:   para
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              30720K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```

AT first I thought it's a bug of `lscpu`. From the man page of `lscpu`:

> Bugs
>          Sometimes in Xen Dom0 the kernel reports wrong data.
>          On virtual hardware the number of cores per socket, etc. can be wrong.

But then I saw that `/proc` of `vm` [not `dom0`] also showing same thing,

```
[arif@vm ~]$ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "physical id" | sort -u | wc -l
1
```